# REGEXP_SUBSTR - how to "avoid" bracket in string

Tags: sql, oracle, brackets, regexp-substr

I have below string in db `Blanket By-Laws Coverage (Building Only) - Form:G00150` and I need to return only "G00150" value.

I'm using this REGEXP_SUBSTR (*pqb.description* is above string)

```
SELECT  MAX(REGEXP_SUBSTR(pqb.description,'(Blanket By-Laws Coverage (Building Only) - Form:)(.*)',1,1,'i',2))    columnname 
FROM    tablename [...]
```

And I'm getting null value for this, I suppose it's because brackets in string, but I don't have an idea how to avoid it.
In 99% of the cases, descriptions do not have brackets, so this REGEXP works, but this is not the case and I cannot find way to make it work

Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Michał

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the brackets and also you need first sub-expression. so use the following `regexp`

```
SELECT  MAX(REGEXP_SUBSTR(pqb.description,
                         'Blanket By-Laws Coverage \(Building Only\) - Form:(.*)',
                          1,1,'i',1) )    columnname 
FROM    tablename [...]
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=54862ef4aa1aadc172475dee7b33713b)

Answer (score 2):

Use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with a capture group around only the form value:

```sql
SELECT MAX(REGEXP_SUBSTR(pqb.description, 'Blanket By-Laws Coverage \(Building Only\) - Form:(\S*)', 1, 1, 'i', 1)) 
FROM tablename;
```

Note that the parentheses around `(Building Only)` are *literal*, and, as such, they should be escaped with backslash.  Also note that in your current query you have another capture group around everything except for the form and value.  You don't need that capture group either, so I have removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Why worry about escaping parens at all?  Don't you just want what's after "`Form:`"?  Note that REGEXP_REPLACE will return the original string if a match is not found, where REGEXP_SUBSTR will return NULL.

```
WITH pqb(description) AS (
  SELECT 'Blanket By-Laws Coverage (Building Only) - Form:G00150' FROM dual
)
--SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '.*Form:(.*)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS Form
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(description, '.*Form:(.*)', '\1') AS Form
from pqb;


FORM  
------
G00150
1 row selected.
```